# How to test if page loads without errors in webdriver c#?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, assert

I want to assert if page loads properly, without any system errors, can you give me some examples?

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("example");
//assert if page loads properly
```

Comment: what do you mean saying "without errors"? what errors?

Comment: like http 404 and similar, when the page does not even load

Comment: Check http://www.ninthavenue.com.au/how-to-get-the-http-status-code-in-selenium-webdriver, it has some samples on how to parse the result for HTTP status codes. So in your case you can look for 200 OK to start with, but there are lots of other codes which also means success...

Comment: that's a valid question and I am struggling with it now. How do I detect `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("gggggoogle.com");` ? it loads a page with some error text browser dependent. Not easy to detect

Answer (score 1):

A good general purpose way to detect if a page loads correctly is to look for an element you expect to exist on the page. If that element doesn't exist, you log an error. If the element does exist you can assume that there were no errors.

You can do a quick check for element existence using the code below.

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> element = driver.FindElements(By.Id("sampleId"));
if (element.Count != 0)
{
    // page loaded properly
}
```

Comment: It really depends on what the OP means by "loads without errors". Your test here won't *generally* detect a page that tries to load a non-existent script file or that has errors in the JavaScript.

Comment: @Louis you are correct but it's a start. Without a list of all errors he is trying to capture, there's no way to provide code to do that.